# Resetting branch after rebasing?

Tags: git, rebase

I was working on a feature branch, `feature` and pushed a commit. There plenty of changes made on `master` and I wanted to pull them on my `feature` breanch.

So I switched to my `master` branch, pulled the changes, then switched back to `feature`. Then I typed in `git rebase master` from my `feature` branch.

Now I'm getting the following:

> On branch feature

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature' by 177 commits.
> (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Did I just mess up? I don't want to push 177 commits. Is there a way to restart this? Maybe delete my branch and then pull it again?

Comment: `push` would just propagate the rebase to the remote. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: `git rebase` works by copying commits (from old-and-lousy to new-and-improved, or at least, that's your goal). But: which commits? The answer is that, if you run `git log master..HEAD` *before you start* your `git rebase`, you will see the commits that `git rebase` will copy. If those aren't the commits you want copied, you need a different command.

Comment: To *undo* your earlier rebase, make sure `git reset --hard` won't lose any uncommitted work, then use `git reset --hard` to put the current `feature` name back where it used to be, probably `feature@{1}` and/or `ORIG_HEAD`. (Use `git log` to inspect `feature@{1}` and/or `ORIG_HEAD` to see if that looks right. Remember that you now have two copies of many commits so look *carefully!*) Then `git reset --hard feature@{1}`, for instance, will set things back (if `feature@{1}` selects the right hash ID).

Comment: Is that all you got, only being ahead of origin/feature? Because if you actually rebased, you should be behind origin/feature as well, in addition to being ahead of it. That commit you said you pushed at the start of your post, you should be behind on that since that exact commit with that exact id is no longer part of your feature branch. If you are **only** ahead, and you have commits on your feature branch not part of master, then I'd say you did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

That's expected after rebasing a branch.
Your origin branch is on top of an out-dated version of master. Since you branched off of master, there have been 177 commits to it.

You can use this command to see, for example, the last 10 commits, so you can confirm that it is actually the latest master and not some random commits.

```
git log --pretty=oneline --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit -10
```

Comment: If they had commits on their feature branch that is not part of master, and that has been pushed (as indicated as part of the start of the question), the rebased local feature branch should be **both** behind and ahead of origin/feature. If it is now only ahead of it, I'd say something went wrong with the rebase, or there is some information missing in the question.

Comment: Indeed. You are correct! Would have expected a "branch diverged" type of message.